# How to delete all files that match a pattern (or older than..) except the newest file that matches the pattern?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a scheduled task / script running that takes a snapshot of a file each 3 hours, but the file is growing and disk space is limited, so each week I want to perform a cleanup.

As for now I do this manually, though, I'm hoping this task can be automated?

What I exactly want, I have a directory which contains this:

```
 B:\>dir
 Volume in drive B is BACKUP
 Volume Serial Number is ****-****

 Directory of B:\

2015-03-04  13:04    <DIR>          MEMORYCRASHDUMPS
2015-03-02  23:59        20 484 150 [20150302235959.082]-Logs.rar
2015-03-03  00:00    <DIR>          Logs
2015-03-01  17:59        67 365 888 [20150301180000.085]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-01  22:50        67 480 576 [20150301230000.368]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-02  00:32        67 480 576 [20150302030000.378]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-02  06:22        67 503 104 [20150302080000.352]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-02  12:59        67 605 504 [20150302130000.084]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-02  17:59        67 740 672 [20150302180000.090]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-02  22:59        67 921 920 [20150302230000.418]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-03  02:58        67 960 832 [20150303030000.088]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-03  07:53        67 966 976 [20150303080000.456]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-03  12:59        68 013 056 [20150303130000.082]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-03  17:59        68 153 344 [20150303180000.081]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-03  22:54        68 339 712 [20150303230000.352]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-04  01:40        68 350 976 [20150304030000.090]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-04  07:51        68 367 360 [20150304080000.358]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-04  12:53        68 452 352 [20150304130000.085]-users.sqlite3
2015-03-04  17:58        68 718 592 [20150304180000.083]-users.sqlite3
```

I want to delete all `./*-users.sqlite3`, except the newest one (Bonus: Except the N newest ones).

Is there a handy build-in windows command for this?

I did already check out a few questions, though they only cover deleting files by date/age or patterns, they do not provide a way to exclude the newest item (only a certain filename).

Comment: As-is you're basically just asking for a product that does "X", which is off-topic for SU.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - It can be done with a simple one liner via FOR /F with SKIP. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/885648/109090)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple - process a directory listing sorted by date descending via FOR /F, and skip the first N rows. Your file names already contain a time stamp that properly sorts chronologically, so you can sort by name.

The following will preserve the 3 most recent files. Just modify the SKIP value as needed.

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d /o-n "[*]-users.sqlite3"') do @del "%F"
```

You can put the above in a batch script and parametize the skip value.

**purgeLog.bat**

```
@echo off
pushd b:\
for /f "skip=%1 delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d /o-n "[*]-users.sqlite3"') do del "%%F"
popd
```

To preserve the 2 most recent logs, you would use:

```
purgeLog 2
```

Comment: If you think that's a "simple" one-liner you're on drugs. :) +1

Comment: Life-saver! I should seriously teach myself batch-skills that are as powerfull as my C++-skills :) One more task i'm going to automate and I'll never have to log-in to the dedicated machine ever again.